# Is it a good practice to declare Context in beginning of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

In my last project in the activities I had a lot of `MyActivity.this` provided to the methods requiring context, so I decided to make it like this in the beginning of the class

```
private Context context = ActivityStage2.this;
```

and then just pass `context` to object methods. So far it works ok, but is it ok at all to declare the Context like that? I mean does that always have the updated state of the MyActivity.this each time the context object is referenced?

Comment: Better to used `Application Level Context`

Comment: I use `getApplicationContext()`, instead of `this`

Comment: If you are working inside an activity, use this, otherwise use getApplicationContext()

Comment: After creating `Context` variable in all activities separately then obvious memory will occupies. So better to use `YourActivityName.this` as a `Context`.

Comment: @Manish Wrong. If you pass the application Context into the `LayoutInflator` you will get an Exception.

Comment: Each context level have their own scope and usage so use them whenever  which one should be used.

Comment: @Manish  I am talk in about separate `Application` class that extends `Application`

Comment: @mmlooloo No i am not. There is another Guys with the same name _Manish_..

Comment: It's a site faulty policy, to allow users to use existing names. I think it has been already discussed on Meta.

Comment: @Manish great, then add some more info about defining that Application class in manifest also. Try to post a comment with meaningful description.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein You absolutely right...Its so bad and now SO not allowed me to change my userName..

Comment: @Manish (11728 rep). After 30 days since the last name change you can change it again.

Comment: @Manish you can change your username after every 30 days. By the way, discussion is going on in another way.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yup. I knew. Thnx for give me this info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can do it but there is no  point in doing it.

You basically "cache" the `this` reference to a field. The field initialization will run just before the constructor body, so every time the object is recreated the reference `context` will be updated. This works similarly to `this`, which points at this instance object.

Now why would you do that? Readability? It seems like you want to use it in inner classes, because you explicitly qualify it with: `ActivityStage2.this`. The java way to qualify the outer class reference from an inner class is well understood by programmers, and here the gain is little. One exception could be anonymous inner classes where you don't have the name of the inner class. In this case caching the reference to the `Activity` makes sense, but I'd rather use a final local variable instead of a field.

Another reason for doing this could be that you need only the `Context` interface instead of the `ActivityStage2` interface: that makes sense theoretically but in practice I wouldn't do it without some other better reason.

Last thing: if you turn your field in a **static** one, you will indeed **leak**.

Comment: so in an Activity I should use "this"?

Comment: so if I am in Activity I should always use "this", and when outside  Activity use the passed "context" or "context.getApplicationContext()" ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, use "this" inside the `Activity`. The application context (getApplicationContext()) is basically a reference to the entire app instance, so you can pass it around activities without leaking memory. On the flip side, you could have a different theme applied to this context, so the styling might be incorrect. Also there are problems with the layout inflater. Which Context to use when is really **another** (long) question, to which you can find many answers here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to do this if you follow the two rules listed bellow:

1. Keep the reference in a instance member. If you use a static field, your `Activity` instance could never be recycled by the GC because your `MainActivity` class has a strong reference to the object. If you really need to do this, use a `WeakReference`.
2. Keep a reference to your `Activity` instance. Do not keep a reference to other activity due to the reasons I have just described above.

Otherwise it all depends on you and your code style :)